# I made changes in stateless widget structure

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, statelesswidget

In vs code  i was writing flutter code in the stateless widget structure i deleted all the immutable word so i changed the stateless widget after that the code want run and its giving me a lot of errors i will past the errors in the end so i tried to delet vs code and i did when i installed it again the problem was still the i tried to reset the vs code so i deleted jason file also the problem still there what should i do and heres is the errors
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G996B in debug mode...
: Error: Undefined name 'immutable'.
@immutable
^^^^^^^^^
: Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
@immutable
^

: Error: Undefined name 'immutable'.
@immutable
^^^^^^^^^
: annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.

@immutable
^
: Error: Undefined name 'immutable'.
@immutable
^^^^^^^^^
: Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
@immutable
^

:

: Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
@immutable
^
: Error: Undefined name 'immutable'.
@immutable
^^^^^^^^^

: Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
@immutable
^
: Error: Undefined name 'immutable'.
@immutable
^^^^^^^^^

: Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
@immutable
^
: Error: Undefined name 'immutable'.
@immutable
^^^^^^^^^
:
: Error: This can't be used as an annotation; an annotation should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
@immutable
^
:

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic data
along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash reports.
This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework, and related tools.
Telemetry is not sent on the very first run.
To disable reporting of telemetry, run this terminal command:
flutter --disable-telemetry.
If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent,
and then no further information will be sent.
This data is collected in accordance with the
Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

As i said i tried to delete vs code with its extention and i even reset the app by deleting jason file but the problem is still there

Comment: If you made changes to the StatelessWidget.dart file, you will need to revert those changes. I would recommend uninstalling and re-installing Flutter